# Pass extension from Twilio to Asterisk

Tags: twilio, asterisk, sip

I am using twilio to manage our IVR, to handle SMS, and for a few other things. After a user calls and goes through the IVR (for example they press 2 for sales or they say they want extension 205) I need it to hand off to Asterisk.

Setting up the trunk isn't my issue. I need to somehow tag it so asterisk knows how to handle the call. If they chose ext 205 on twilio, I need asterisk to automatically ring ext 205.

I am using a minimal version of asterisk basically for sip registration and voicemail and the rest is done by twilio.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in code? Or is my best bet to create a different trunk for each extension. That seems like it would get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution is make IVR on asterisk. This solution also will be MUCH less costly.

But if you really want... On twilio setup via SIP tag

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip

set url to sip:0000+exten@your_asterisk_ip

On asterisk setup trunk to twilio server or allowguest=yes and default context to 'goext'

After that goext context something like this

```
[goext]
exten => _0000XXX,1,Set(ext=${EXTEN:4})
same => n,Dial(SIP/${ext},,o)
```

0000 replace with some random code, that required for prevent bots calls when allowguest=yes.

Comment: A good portion of the calls are routed directly to cell phones, using Asterisk for the IVR would require the use of two trunks (one from twilio to asterisk, then one from asterisk to the cell phone), so costs would actually be quite higher.

Using twilio is also more fail-safe, if the server goes down (or the office loses internet) the IVR will still function and can automatically route calls to cell phones.

I will try your approach and see how it works. I am still setting up a new test server so I'll have a clean config to play with. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Twilio charge you x2 to x4 of usual cost for almost any calls. So it is hard imagine any system which will cost more then twilio. Trunk from twilio to asterisk will not be charged, it is SIP. You already have asterisk in your setup. Build all without asterisk or deal with fault tolerance of your asterisk solution. start asterisk in EC2 with auto-start second or use two vps with failover.

Comment: You also can put all exts on twilio. yes, that will be more fault tolerant and more costly.